# Change notification without INotifyPropertyChanged? (excerpt from Pro WPF in C# 2010)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

While reading Pro WPF in C# 2010 the author writes:

"You can raise an event for each property. In this case, the event must have the name PropertyNameChanged (for example, UnitCostChanged). It’s up to you to fire the event when the property is changed."

Could someone confirm this feature works? I was experimenting and not able to reproduce this behavior (I want to see if this works so then I can do some experimenting with System.Reflection.Emit to create dynamic types)

**EDIT:** I should clarify the emphasis here is to implement change notification WITHOUT implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, as this is what the book is claiming

Here's the POCO I am testing with:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_FirstName != value)
            {
                _FirstName = value;
                if (FirstNameChanged != null) 
                {
                    FirstNameChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I bound it to a DataGrid and have a timer in the background update the FirstName property randomly every few seconds but the DataGrid never fires

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=MyEmployees}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The FirstNameChanged event is always null (I thought the binding engine might automatically subscribe to it if it detected it according to the naming convention). MyEmployees is just an ObservableCollection

Can someone confirm if this feature the author mentions, does indeed work and if I'm making a mistake?

**EDIT:** for the benefit of anyone who thinks I'm misinterpreting the text:

"You can use three approaches to solve this problem:

You can make each property in the Product class a dependency property using the
syntax you learned about in Chapter 4. (In this case, your class must derive from
DependencyObject.) Although this approach gets WPF to do the work for you
(which is nice), it makes the most sense in elements—classes that have a visual
appearance in a window. It’s not the most natural approach for data classes like
Product.

**You can raise an event for each property. In this case, the event must have the
name PropertyNameChanged (for example, UnitCostChanged). It’s up to you to
fire the event when the property is changed.**

You can implement the System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
interface, which requires a single event named PropertyChanged. You must then
raise the PropertyChanged event whenever a property changes and indicate which
property has changed by supplying the property name as a string. It’s still up to
you to raise this event when a property changes, but you don’t need to define a
separate event for each property."

Comment: Not sure if that syntax will work but you pretty sure you need to decorate the class as implementing iNotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: No, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid - in the book, it mentions the 3 techniques are a.) use DependencyProperties b.) use INotifyPropertyChanged (which I'm already familar with) c.) use this convention-based approach which does NOT implement INotifyPropertyChanged ..that's kind of the whole point of what I'm testing here :)

Comment: OK understand but I don't think that is what is being claimed.  You can raise the event directly without a NotifyPropertyChanged method but I think you still need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: In the book, the 3 approaches are described in a mutually-exclusive fashion

Comment: Those are methods to notify when a property changes, but it does not mean that the 'binding engine' automatically suscribes to an event with that convention. The binding engine only works (automatically, at least) with Dependency Properties and INotifyPropertyChanged (or INotifyCollectionChanged)

Comment: Since the passage was in the context of a chapter dedicated to data-binding I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) this was a means to implement INotify-ish behavior. I'll see if I can reach out to the author to get clarification but I suspect you are all right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say it's very possible to implement change notifications in your POCO's without using either INotifyPropertyChanged or dependency properties, like it's being claimed in the book, unless i'm completely missing the point of the question.

If you raise an event called ***{Propertyname}*Changed** from your POCO when the value of a property has changed, the WPF binding system will pick that up, and update the relevant bindings.

See this small program for a demonstration - it's the simplest thing I could think of, but I guess it should work in your case as well.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <Button Content="Change name" Click="changeNameClick" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private SimpleObject so = new SimpleObject();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.so = new SimpleObject();
        so.Name = "Initial value";

        this.DataContext = so;

        var t = new DispatcherTimer(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (s, e) => { this.so.Name = "Name changed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(); },
            Dispatcher);
    }

    private void changeNameClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.so.Name = "New value!!";
    }
}

public class SimpleObject
{
    private string mName = null;

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return mName; }
        set
        {
            if (mName != value)
            {
                mName = value;

                if (NameChanged != null)
                    NameChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler NameChanged;
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! I knew I wasn't crazy lol. My original code now works but only after I changed "PropertyChangedEventHandler" to a plain "EventHandler" ..any idea why that is? Is this "feature" documented anywhere? Fantastic, thank you SO MUCH

Comment: Hehe, no sorry, I really have no idea why that is. I remember hearing about this some time back, but have never actually used it in my own code. And I can't really seem to find any real documentation anywhere, so it's probably not a very widely used technique..

Comment: I have some additional insight if you're interested - from inspection, the default PropertyDescriptor on the POCO type is lazy-loaded an instance of ReflectPropertyDescriptor - of particular interest is the SupportsChangeEvents boolean property. This is set to true by the runtime if the class follows the propertynameChanged naming convention (though it doesn't work unless I used a plain EventHandler) or implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The absence of either will cause this to be false. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.supportschangeevents.aspx

Comment: Ah I see - that's interesting. Hope this helps you solve your problem!

Comment: Interesting discussion and a nice solution. I haven't peeked their code but I imagine that the value of the SupportsChangeEvents property is determined by the search for an event with type EventHandler and the name <property>Changed.

I wonder if WPF is using WeakEventManager to subscribe though; wouldn't want memory leaks.

Comment: @PeterHansen NameChanged seems to always be null.  Where is it set?

Comment: There is no point in passing in the property name using `PropertyChangedEventArgs`, since the event name itself contains this information.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you mention applies to WPF as well as to Windows Forms (WinForms).

- *WPF, see*: "Providing Change Notifications" section in [Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx) on MSDN.
- *WinForms, see*: [How to: Apply the PropertyNameChanged Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229615%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Great to finally have a definitive link on MSDN describing it

Answer (score -2):

No, with WPF, you need to use `DependencyProperties` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  For collections, `INotifyCollectionChanged` will do the trick too.

Comment: Apparently you can - see answer.

Comment: There's actually a 4th way - you can always manually raise the UpdateTarget() method on the BindingExpression but not sure I would count that